# how can I run a jar from /usr/local/bin like a Terminal command?

Tags: java, macos, terminal, command-line-interface, macos-sierra

I have made a calculator CLI calculator app in Java that I would like to use. Since I am actually going to use it quite often, I do not like the idea of typing the long path all the time.
I have read an article on StackoverFlow that you can place a .sh command into the /usr/bin folder, but after the El Capitan update, all System folders are locked even for the root user. So, again, I did some more research, and I found that /usr/local/bin folder is specifically made for "home-made" commands for the terminal. I have made a calculator.sh file with the following code:

```
    #!/bin/sh 
    -jar /Users/mac/Desktop/Данила/my_apps/calculator.jar "$*"
```

The article said that I should place it in the /usr/bin folder, but because it is locked, I placed it in the /usr/local/bin, thinking that it is practically the same thing, and that it should work. Of course after I placed it in there and tried to run "calculator" command in the terminal, it did not work at all. I figured that it might need a "chmod" command to make it work. So I used chmod +x /path, but afterwards it still would not work. Right now I am stumped, so any help would be welcome.

Comment: how would you run it from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is /usr/local/bin on your path? `echo $PATH` to find out.

Second, are you sure you pasted the above script properly?

It seems to be missing `java` on the command line.

I would expect it to look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh 
java -jar /Users/mac/Desktop/Данила/my_apps/calculator.jar "$*"
```

Also, since you named it `calculator.sh`, you have to run it using that name.

The `.sh` extension isn't needed, so you could just call it `calculator`.

Answer (score 1):

To this I recommend you create an alias.

```
alias test="java -jar /full/path/to/jar.jar"
```

And "test" is a command now, if you like get this command allways add it into .bash_profile.